# Extract dictionary value from column in data frame with Vaex

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow, vaex

I applied on my dataframe the next command

df['date_article'] = df.pagePath.str.extract_regex(pattern='(?P<digit>/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)')

And this created the column 'date_article'

| pagePath | date_article |
| --- | --- |
| '/empresas/2021/10/22/tiendas-no-participan-buen' | {'digit': '/2021/10/22/'} |
| '/finanzas-personales/2021/10/22/pueden-cobrar-c | {'digit': '/2021/10/22/'} |

Now I want to left only the date in 'date_article'.

Expected output

| pagePath | date_article |
| --- | --- |
| '/empresas/2021/10/22/tiendas-no-participan-buen' | '/2021/10/22/' |
| /finanzas-personales/2021/10/22/pueden-cobrar-c | '/2021/10/22/' |

I tried many things but nothing seems to work

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: `{'digit': '/2021/10/22/'}` is a string or a dict?

Comment: Seems to be a dict. The documentation says this -> -Returns: an expression containing a struct with field names corresponding to capture group identifiers.

Comment: https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.expression.StringOperations.extract_regex

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [`extract_regex`](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.expression.StringOperations.extract_regex) returns a struct series:

> Extract substrings defined by a regular expression using Apache Arrow
> (Google RE2 library).
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> pattern (str) – A regular expression which needs to contain named capture groups, e.g. ‘letter’ and ‘digit’ for the regular expression
> ```
>
> ‘(?P[ab])(?Pd)’.
>
> Returns
>
> ```
> an expression containing a struct with field names corresponding to capture group identifiers.
> ```

So you will need to extract the field you want out of the struct.  I'm not a Vaex expert but maybe something like:

```
struct_series = df.pagePath.str.extract_regex(pattern='(?P<digit>/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)')
df['date_article'] = struct_series.struct.get('digit')
```

Comment: Thank you!  As you said  df['date_article'] = df['date_article'].struct.get('digit') solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```py
df['date_article'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['digit'], axis=1)
```

Comment: I tried this and give me this error:

TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_article':[{'digit': '/2021/10/22/'}]})
df['date_article'] = df['date_article'].apply(lambda x: x['digit'])
```

This uses a lambda function which returns the value of `digit` key on the specified column and assigns it again. Why you do not use just the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_article':['sdfsdf/2021/10/22/']})
df['date_article'] = df['date_article'].str.extract('(/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/)')
```